# How to make redirect from unpublished page to error 301

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have to delete or unpublish a cloudpage, but I would like to redirect everyone who will visit this deleted/unpublished cloudpage to another page, so the deleted/unpublished cloudpage should show error 301. I see that by default an unpublished/deleted cloudpage shows error 404. Is it possible to change it to error 301?

Answer (score 2):

In essence you want something that is not there to do something - this might be hard to do and Marketing Cloud does not give us the option to do this when unpublishing CloudPages.

If the redirect is more important than actually having the page unpublished, keep the page published, but remove all actual content and replace it with a script that does the redirect. This won't save your super messages from being consumed, but will keep the URL functional.